# Passing DateTimeKind in ASP.NET Web Api 2.0 GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api2, nodatime

I'm having trouble with DateTimes in my ASP.NET C# Web Api 2 project. I need to pass through an ISO 8601 date in my query string as follows:

```
api/resource?at=2016-02-14T23:30:58Z
```

My controller method is as follows

```
[HttpGet("/resource")]
public IActionResult GetResource([FromQuery]DateTime? at = null)
{
    if (!at.HasValue)
    {
        at = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
    else
    {
        at = DateTime.SpecifyKind(at.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Notice the little hack - the date is coming in with a DateTimeKind of Local, despite being specified with the 'Z' signifying UTC.  Dates should always be passed in UTC although I would ideally not like this to be a constraint.  I am using NodaTime internally and only expose DateTime in the query and response models for legacy reasons.

- Why are my dates parsed to a DateTimeKind of local?
- How can I read my UTC dates from query strings using ASP.NET web api 2?

Comment: What if call a ToUniversalTime() to convert to UTC?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46308876/634824) in the dup post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, the time-zone offset is preserved. You could then either use it directly, or convert it to a `DateTime` via the `UtcDateTime` property.

```
 DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2016-02-14T23:30:58Z");
 DateTime dt = dto.UtcDateTime;
```

---

```
[HttpGet("/resource")]
public IActionResult GetResource([FromQuery]DateTimeOffset? at = null)
{
    if (!at.HasValue)
    {
        at = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, that is the solution.  Still find it odd that a DateTime query would simply ignore any time zone information when there is available a DateTimeKind.Utc and various local times, but this does cater for that.