# How to configure model binding to get UTC DateTime via form

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

When I tried to send DateTime object via form-data .NET-MVC binds it into DateTime object with the server's local timezone. 
But in the another case DateTime object is binded correctly if it has been received via JSON.

Using form-data
[image: Using form]
Using JSON body
[image: Using JSON]

a piece of Startup.cs where MvcCore is added

```
services.AddMvcCore(opt =>
{
    opt.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new EmptyStringModelBinder());
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
.AddFormatterMappings()
.AddCacheTagHelper()
.AddJsonFormatters()
.AddCors()
.AddAuthorization();
```

The example model:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public DateTime item { get; set; }
}
```

The example controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult TestPost([FromForm] TestClass item)
//public IActionResult TestPost([FromBody] TestClass item)
{
    var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var date = item.item;
    var UTCDate = date.ToUniversalTime();
    return Ok(UTCDate);
}
```

There is a test project about that issue
[Test project](https://github.com/ShefardPT/TestProject/tree/DateTimeUTCFromDb)

Comment: please post the code you have so we're able to help you

Comment: What kind of the specific codelines do you need?

Comment: everything related to your question... namely the view, the controller action and the model

Comment: I've added the controller action method and the model now.

Comment: The JSON string specifies the timezone explicitly with that `Z`. What does the form field contain? I bet it doesn't contain either `Z` or an offset

Comment: You can see at screenshots there are 'Z' postfix in the both cases.

Comment: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/46308876/3739842

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ASP.Net MVC model binder treat incoming date as UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293440/how-to-make-asp-net-mvc-model-binder-treat-incoming-date-as-utc)