# How do it fix an API Get request with a Datetime parameter that is resulting in "01/01/0001 00:00:00"

Tags: c#, json.net, datetime-format, model-binding, converters

I have an API endpoint like `https://localhost:5001/myResource?fromdate=22-12-2019`.When I do a Get request the **RequestFromDate** field in the **SearchFilters** object is set to “**01/01/0001 00:00:00**" and not a valid date. The user can **ONLY** send the date in this format **dd-MM-yyyy**.How do I fix this problem? Am i missing something in my startup class?. I’m using **Newtonsoft** (Core3.1)

```
    public class SearchFilters
    {
       [FromQuery(Name = "fromDate")]
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    }
```

MyController

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync([FromQuery] SearchFilters searchFilters)
    {
    ..
    }
```

Section in my startup where I setup NewtonSoftJson

```
    services
        .AddControllers(options => { options.EnableEndpointRouting = false; })
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = true;
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        })
        .AddJsonApi(opt => opt.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = true);
```

I tried adding the below but without success

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
 options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyDateFormatConverter());
}
```

My Custom Converter

```
public class MyDateFormatConverter: IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public MyDateFormatConverter()
   {
       DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
   }
}
```

Comment: `[FromQuery]` parameters aren't going to be deserialized using Newtonsoft, which is only for deserializing JSON.  `"01/01/0001 00:00:00"` looks like `default(DateTime)` -- what you would get if the parameter wasn't assigned at all.

Comment: If i dont pass in a value, the [FromQuery] field is set to "01/01/0001 00:00:00". But if I set the param to "01-23-2019" it comes out as "23/01/2019 00:00:00" . I would like to get "23/01/2019 00:00:00" when i set the query string is set to "23-01-2019"

Comment: Right.  But `MyDateFormatConverter` isn't going to do that since it's for JSON not query parameters. I think you need to write a custom model binder, see [Custom DateTime Model Binding in ASP.NET Core Web API](http://www.vickram.me/custom-datetime-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-web-api) or [ASP.NET Core model binder deserilises UTC time string to local time rather than UTC time #11584](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11584#issuecomment-506007647) for examples.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46308876/3744182) by [Matt Johnson-Pint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson-pint) to [How to make ASP.Net MVC model binder treat incoming date as UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10293440/3744182) and/or [Change default format for DateTime parsing in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41642800/3744182) are what you want.